Unable to add admin system user and generate permanent access token for whatsapp api
Error performing query
Unable to add admin system user and generate permanent access token for whatsapp api.
Note :-  Error performing query
"I'm encountering an issue while trying to add an admin system user and generate a permanent access token for the WhatsApp API. The process fails with an 'error performing query' message. Interestingly, this problem only occurs with the app I'm developing for my second business; the admin system user for my first business works fine. Could this be a problem on Facebook's end? or this is the problem my end "
